# Parse conversion to MLab and Beanstalk and Swift AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mlab

I am trying to migrate from Parse using the MLab-AWS Elastic Beanstalk process.  I have input the Parse APPID and the MLabID etc into the AWS settings.  I have the db setup and all the Parse tables/data imported into MLab.

I can't seem to find any documentation on what needs to replace the Parse initializations AppID Tokens etc. in the AppDelegate to call the Mlab db?

From looking at other conversion for Parse eveyone seems to include how to change the AppDelegate to communicate with their service but after days, I can't find anything for the Mlab/AWS migration that references how the app accesses the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Elastic Beanstalk dashboard. Click on the parse server you set up. You'll see the server URL at the top of the page. Use that for the ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server. Here is the client code you should use to replace in the AppDelegate

let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "APP_ID"
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://your_server.com:1337/parse"
})

Also, make sure you add /parse to the end of the server URL or it won't work.